# How to cancel or close an order that has been invoiced through the API

Tags: api, order-status, cancel-orders

I know in previous older versions (still 2.0) that I could cancel an order in processing with an invoice but recently that seems to have stopped working for a few of my clients.  ie: 
/V1/orders/{id}/cancel

So I have to change the order cancelation process somehow.  Leaving the order closed may also work.

What is the process for cancelling an order that has been invoiced through the API?

What endpoints do I use?

What information do I need?

Comment: The API doesnt seem to be changed in any release after 2.0, please post your error while cancelling order.

Comment: There is no error only "false" is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works as expected. If previously you could have canceled an order that was fully invoiced then the problem was in the past.
Here is how canceling an order (via api or not) works.
The cancel order goes through the  `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::cancel()` method.
The concrete implementation for this method is `Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService::cancel()`.
and this method looks like this:

```
public function cancel($id)
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($id);
    if ($order->canCancel()) {
        $order->cancel();
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you are getting the response `false` it means that `$order->canCancel()` returns `false`.
Let's go to that method in the `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` class.

```
public function canCancel()
{
    if (!$this->_canVoidOrder()) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->canUnhold()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$this->canReviewPayment() && $this->canFetchPaymentReviewUpdate()) {
        return false;
    }

    $allInvoiced = true;
    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()) {
            $allInvoiced = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($allInvoiced) {
        return false;
    }

    $state = $this->getState();
    if ($this->isCanceled() || $state === self::STATE_COMPLETE || $state === self::STATE_CLOSED) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, there are a few branches that return `false`.
The one that handles the invoiced items is this:

```
    $allInvoiced = true;
    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()) {
            $allInvoiced = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($allInvoiced) {
        return false;
    }
```

This means that if all the order items are invoiced, the order cannot be canceled.
but if there is at least one item that is not invoiced, the order can be canceled.
If you really need this to happen, you can rewrite or plugin the `canCancel` method and exclude the check for all invoiced items.

Comment: What I need is how to accomplish the task through the API.  What I have determined is that once an order has been invoiced it can NOT be cancelled.  But it can be closed.  The steps are as follows 1. look up the invoice 2. take the invoice id (entityid).  3. Use the invoice id and add any extra stuff like shipping costs to the refund call.  If I get nothing better you can get the points but I will outline this solution.